# Getting this code to work for all sheets in a workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I need this code to work for all sheets:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Right now I've been adding it to every sheet one by one, but how do I just add it to the workbook so every sheet has it?

Comment: AFAIK you can't use VBA to write VBA in another sheet's class module, you have to write it by hand

Comment: Application.screenupdating is not worksheet specific.  It is application as in all of excel.  Also it automatically returns to true as soon as the sub that turned it false ends.

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried adding the `screenupdating` to the workbook object, but it didn't work until I put it on an actual sheet?

Comment: @AmericanSlime Try to put it in the `Workbook_SheetChange` event

Comment: @Barranka I'm not sure what means. Within VBA there is a list of 'Microsoft Excel Objects' which shows all the sheets, then the workbook at the bottom. If I put the code into a sheet, works, but if I put it into the workbook one, doesn't.

Comment: you need to select it from the drop downs at the top, so you get this                        Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub

Comment: @user5414798 Thank you, between you and Barranka I was able to see what my options were and they had the exact one I was looking for.

Comment: If their comments assisted you, you can always  up vote their comment(if not done so already).

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This worked for me. What I had to do was change my object to include the workbook itself. I clicked on the dropdown to see my available options which is where I found the one I needed.

Bad: `Worksheet_SelectionChange`

Good: `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange`